# Changing a bit in IV of MD5

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, initialization-vector, md5, preimage-resistance

It is obvious that changing even one bit in data or IV (initialization vector) will change the hash value a lot. I want to know if, for example, changing a single bit within the $IV$ in MD5 can be neutralized by changing the message data using a specific algorithm?

I think the differential attack on MD5 can be helpful but I don't know how?

Comment: I've made this specific for MD5 as the attacks on hash functions differ. You can maybe ask a more generic question once this one has been answered.